# Is there a lightweight way to include GDI rendered content when printing with WPF?

Tags: wpf, printing, interop, gdi

One of the projects I work on has some pre-existing reports that are printed via MFC's printing support and rendered more or less directly to a printer DC via GDI. We've started doing some new (unrelated) reports via WPF/XAML since we're transitioning new UI to WPF anyway and it's so much better to work with for layout.

The other shoe has finally dropped, and I've got the need to add some new functionality to an existing printed report, and the new functionality practically begs to be implemented with WPF. Our existing WPF reports are implemented via XAML pages sent to an XpsDocument (in-memory, not on disk) via XpsDocumentWriter. I would like to be able to continue to use this strategy, and take the approach of writing WPF/XAML reports that happen to have some pages rendered via GDI.

My first naive attempt was to embed an HwndHost in the UIElement that gets rendered in the XpsDocumentWriter, but that doesn't seem to work. No surprise but it was worth a try.

The next obvious solution, IMO, would be to render the GDI graphics to an appropriate sized and scaled bitmap, and render that bitmap to a page in the XpsDocument. That would work, but page-sized bitmaps (especially in-memory ones) seem like a recipe for high memory usage and poor performance on slower computers.

Ideally I'd like to render the GDI content to a metafile or some other vector format that could then be translated to XPS. But this has to be an automatic process that works every time since it's just a document printing feature. OTOH it's an application for in-house users so we can put up with *some* performance degredation

WPF development is not my main task, so I'd describe myself as a novice without much detailed knowledge of the underlying details. I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing something obvious before I revert to using a bitmap as the transfer medium, although I haven't turned up any other decent options in my search so far.

Anything I should be looking into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this would be to create a WriteableBitmap in WPF and blit the GDI drawn image directly to it so it can be rendered in your XPS document. An initial step could be to do a straight blit from your GDI DC (get a pointer to GDI DC, pointer to WriteableBitmap and use Platform Invoke to call memcpy). Later work could involve converting the MFC GDI drawing to vanilla WPF (using a library such as WriteableBitmapEx which has gdi like drawing methods).

Although the first approach above would involve two bitmaps, its the best way I can currently think of without a huge re-write. The second method may or may not be possible out of the box, since WriteableBitmaps's drawing support is not as extended as GDI. A final method I just thought of would be to use GDI via Platform Invoke and draw directly on the WriteableBitmap surface. This would allow a port without a massive re-write and would give you the performance you need, while keeping the code familiar.

Comment: Thanks. I had hoped to avoid manual rasterization via bitmaps (primarily because of pixel resolution headaches when dealing with printing) but it seems like this might be the only practical way. I guess that makes the answer to my question "No".

Comment: I'm afraid so, the rendering engines in wpf and gdi are completely different. Let me ask, if you have a solution in gdi already (does it look good in print?), then could you not wrap that code up into a c++ dll and modify to cope with different resolutions? Ie pass a width, height, dpi to it. Then call it from c# to draw and perform a blit to WrirableBitmap each time the user changes dpi or render target size?

Comment: For Windows 7 there is gdi support built directly into the xps print driver. Sadly not for vista or xp:  http://blogs.technet.com/b/print/archive/2009/12/01/towards-an-improved-windows-7-gdi-to-xps-conversion-experience.aspx

Comment: The current GDI solution is used for printing and already handles different resolutions. My worry with the bitmap blit approach is the size of the bitmaps needed for the simple approach you outline, considering I'd need full pages rendered in GDI, not just small portions of a page. It may not work out to be a problem but a full page at 600 DPI is fairly big, even in grayscale. I may be worrying too much about it though.